# Using ArcGIS Raster Calculator to calculate MSAVI2 based on Landsat 8 OLI bands 4 and 5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, raster-calculator, landsat, ndvi

I would like to calculate a Modified Soil-Adjusted Vegetation Index 2 on the basis of Landsat 8 OLI imagery, bands 5 (NIR) and 4 (RED), using the Raster Calculator. The formula should be:

[image]
I have tried to convert this using the following map algebra expression in the Raster Calculator:

MSAVI2 = (2 * "NIR layer" + 1 - SquareRoot((2 * "NIR layer" + 1) ^ 2  - 8 * ("NIR layer" - "RED layer"))) / 2

The returned values are between 0.5 and 58113.5. They should be between -1 and 1 though, so something is not right.

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you convert to reflectance before applying the formula?

Comment: Have you converted the DNs to TOA reflectance? I'm not familiar with MSAVI2 specifically, but for NDVI you must convert before doing the raster algebra. See [this](http://grindgis.com/blog/vegetation-indices-arcgis) tutorial as an example.

Comment: i would write with more ( ) between the sentences

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use many examples that I've found at internet. All them failed.
So I've build one by myself...

The equation that worked for me was:

```
((2*Float("IMAGE.tif - Band_4"))+1-(Power(((Power(((2*Float("IMAGE.tif - Band_4"))+1),2))-8*(Float("IMAGE.tif - Band_4")-Float("IMAGE.tif - Band_3"))),0.5)))/2
```

Hope that it work for you!

Answer (score 1):

It's ok, but don't use `y = arguments` syntax, only use `arguments`. In your case:

```
(2 * "NIR layer" + 1 - SquareRoot((2 * "NIR layer" + 1) ^ 2 - 8 * ("NIR layer" - "RED layer"))) / 2
```

As Mikkel says, convert values to reflectance before apply this index. Check [this link](https://landsat.usgs.gov/using-usgs-landsat-8-product) for Landsat 8. All information is in `MTL.txt` file.